# How to categorise rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a Table in my database that looks somewhat like this:

```
Toyota RAV4             #
#########################
Kia Sportage            #
Mercedes-Benz M-Class   # 
Honda CRV               #
Suzuki Grand Vitara     # 
Nissan Xterra           # 
Lincoln Navigator       # 
Toyota Land Cruiser     #
```

However I need to label the corresponding car size next to each car to get something like this

```
Toyota RAV4             #  Size
##################################
Kia Sportage            #  Small
Mercedes-Benz M-Class   #  Medium
Honda CRV               #  Small
Suzuki Grand Vitara     #  Small
Nissan Xterra           #  Medium
Lincoln Navigator       #  Large
Toyota Land Cruiser     #  Large
```

how could I achieve this?

Comment: add a column called `size`?

Comment: not exactly. Im trying to add the corresponding size of the car (that I know based on its name) to each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a column called size it will require an ALTER Table command.

Then you will need to Update each row and set the size manually? I think this is what you want to do

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do. I appologise that my question was quite vague, I guess ill look into the ALTER Table command

Comment: Its fine, alter table is very straight forward so is Update :)